# How can I make a windows account only accessible during certain hours?

Tags: user-accounts

I work from home and have trouble sometimes resisting the urge to recreate when I'd be better off working. I'd like to make an account exclusively for recreation and only have it available to me after 6PM.

How best to go about it?

Comment: You will always as an admin be able to get around restrictions you apply so there is no technical answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a standard user account and restrict its login times by using the
[net user command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771865(v=ws.11)).

For example, to limit the user john to logon only on Monday-Friday from 6pm to 12pm,
and unrestricted during the weekend, use the command:

```
net user john /time:M-F,18:00-23:59;Sa-Su,00:00-23:59
```

You may undo the restrictions with:

```
net user john /time:all
```

As you can always undo your own restrictions, this supposes some sort of
code-of-honor on your part to obey your own restrictions.

Comment: This will only allow times to set exactly on the hour. Otherwise, this is exactly what I was looking for, and it will do very nicely for my purposes. Thank you!